# Error when Creating DIscord Bot (javascript)

Tags: javascript, discord

Here's the code. the error is that message is not defined. I am trying to create an argument that is the value for a "coinflip." I'm new to coding with node.js and the discord documentation and this has been puzzling me for a while. I have figured out that the issue has to do something with the coinflip or test command, but commenting them out creates the same problem. Am I missing something?

```
//VARIABLES
const Discord = require('discord.js');

//const db = require("quick.db");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '..';

const fs = require('fs');


// DO THIS LATER: client.user.setStatus("20 bobux");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command)
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('PotatoBot has succesfully booted up! A random number between 1 and 8 is: ' + Math.random(1,8));
});
// client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    // the rest of your code
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(command === 'pinged'){
        client.commands.get('pinged').execute(message,args);
    }   else if(command === 'commands' || command === 'help' || command === 'tutorial'){
        //going to try to integrate this in commands.js but this will do for now
        //client.commands.get('commands').execute(message,args);
        const commandsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#696969')
        .setTitle('All commands for potatobot')
        // .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
        .setAuthor('This bot is in the pre-alpha stages, so expect more in the coming future.', 'https://i.imgur.com/KfIIfRL.jpg',)
        .setDescription('Prefix is ".."')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/B6JXgKj.png')
        .addFields(
            // { name: 'Regular field title', value: '1' },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
            { name: '..commands', value: 'Shows this screen with all available commands as of the latest update.', inline: true },
            { name: '..pinged', value: 'A fun little command to test out the bot', inline: true },
            { name: '..socials', value: 'Coming soon!', inline: true },
        )
        //.addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('dont tell the owner that he sucks at coding')
        message.channel.send(commandsEmbed);
} 
    else if(command === 'socials'){
            //will do this later low priority
            client.commands.get('socials').execute(message,args);
            /*const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#696969')
            .setTitle('Some title')
            .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
            .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
            .setDescription('Some description here')
            .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Regular field title', value: '1' },
                { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                { name: 'Inline field title', value: '2', inline: true },
                { name: 'Inline field title', value: '3', inline: true },
            )
            .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
            .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('dont tell the owner that he sucks at coding', 'https://i.imgur.com/pIwlyOy.jpg')
            message.channel.send(exampleEmbed); */
    }
    else if(command === 'coinflip'){
        
        client.commands.get('coinflip').execute(message,args);
        
        
}
// using the new `command` variable, this makes it easier to manage!
// you can switch your other commands to this format as well
else if (command === 'test') {
    if (!args.length) {
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
        }
        else if (args[0] === 'bruh') {
            return message.channel.send('moment');

        
        
        }
        else {
            return message.channel.send('placeholder'); //trying to figure out how to send ${args}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `// client.on('message', message => {`

Comment: ikegami I did that and it seems to work, however now this error shows up:internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Caleb'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your message event code inside the ready event block. http://discord.js.org/ has different events that can be listened for. The ready event handles when the script successfully connects to the discord api. So anything that runs there will run from the moment the bot is online.

You need to listen for a different event called message. The message event will get triggered whenever a message is sent whether it's in a Direct Message or Discord Server.

```
client.on('message', message => {

    // Your code that previously had message undefined goes here

});
```